# Flexslider renders viewport off by 1px

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, flexslider

So I'm building this site and everything is working great.  However I just realized that flexslider is cutting less than 1px off of the right side of the viewport only on desktop sized displays.....  I have looked for answers to similar questions and nothing is working.  Help!

[image]

http://staging.aidanspencer.com

Answer (score 1):

While I can't replicate this issue right now in Chrome (what browser are you using?) it's most likely caused by this: in your CSS, your width is larger than 100%.

```
.flex-viewport {
    width: 100.1% !important;
    border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
}
```

Drop that down to 100% and you should see this issue disappear.

(Note that usually the issue would still occur because the border would be *outside* the 100% width, but because you're using [border-box for box-sizing](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) the border is included in the width calculation)

Comment: Thanks for looking at it.  That was actually added after the problem occurred to try and correct it. The width of the viewport would be set to 1066.64 px and the width of the slides was being set to 1067px. So my border was cut off.  I ended up just removing the border on the content and setting a border around the viewport. That's not exactly what I wanted to do but it looks fine. Once again, thank you very much for looking at it!  Oh and I'm using chrome on a mac

Comment: Glad you solved it. Might be useful for future questions to post the relevant CSS in your question (or on pastebin) so you can keep dev'ing while people look at your question. Otherwise we end up looking at code that you've already changed :)

Comment: I completely agree, I was behind schedule on the project and a little bit in panic mode, haha.  I'll make sure to paste some code next time.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you mean...

The problem is here:

```
.flex-viewport {
    width: 100.1% !important;
    border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
}
```

This code is in global.css file line 74. Here: http://staging.aidanspencer.com/wp-content/themes/aidan_spencer_2016/assets/css/global.css:74

Then, change the width:

```
.flex-viewport {
    width: 100% !important;
    border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
}
```

Problem solved, everyone is happy.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at it but I actually updated that css.  Basically the problem was occurring when flexslider rendered the viewport.  The width of the viewport would be set to 1066.64 px and the width of the slides was being set to 1067px.  So my border was cut off.  I ended up just removing the border on the content and setting a border around the viewport.  That's not exactly what I wanted to do but it looks fine.  Once again, thank you very much for looking at it!

Comment: Okey. Everyone is happy again. :)